# Firestore nested onSnapshot await/async

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm having an issue with the onSnapshot method. It won't await for the second onsnapshot call, so the returned value is not correct. The users fetched in the second onsnapshot call, will be showed later in the console log when the value already has returned.

If you prefer an other structure, I am open to any solutions and suggestions!!:)
Thank you all.

Console logs: https://imgur.com/a/vhm61nu.png

```js
export const FirebaseGetStrikeLists2 = async (houseId: string) => {
    let strikes: StrikeListDocument[] = [];

    firestore()
        .collection(FirebaseConstraints.HouseCollection)
        .doc(houseId)
        .collection(FirebaseConstraints.StrikeSubCollection)
        .onSnapshot(async x => {
            x.forEach(async x => {
                const strikeListDocument = x.data() as StrikeListDocument
                strikeListDocument.users = []
                strikeListDocument.id = x.id;

                x.ref.collection(FirebaseConstraints.UserCollection).onSnapshot(
                    async x => {
                        let strikeListUsers: StrikeListDocumentUser[] = [];
                        x.forEach(async y => {
                            let userDocument = y.data() as StrikeListDocumentUser;
                            strikeListUsers.push(userDocument)
                        })
                        await Promise.all(strikeListUsers)
                        console.log('users found: ', strikeListUsers.length)
                        strikeListDocument.users = strikeListUsers
                    })
                console.log('users set in array: ', strikeListDocument.users.length)
                strikes.push(strikeListDocument)
            })
        })
    return strikes;
}
```

My firestore structure looks like this:
/houses/{HouseID}/strikelists/{StrikeListID}/users/{UserID}

**EDIT:**

I've made it work in a different class. First I tried to let the code wait and then return it, but couldn't find a solution for it. So I changed a bit in my structure. Whenever the data is recivied it will update the state (must be in the same file). I am using mobx for the observable.

ps: This code can also be called from a UI component and change it to a useState hook.

Now it looks like this:

```js
@observable private _strikeLists: StrikeListDocument[] | undefined;

export const firestoreStrikeListSubscription = (houseId: string) => {
    firestore()
        .collection(FirebaseConstraints.HouseCollection)
        .doc(houseId)
        .collection(FirebaseConstraints.StrikeSubCollection)
        .onSnapshot(x => {
            x.forEach(x => {
                let strikeListDocument = x.data() as StrikeListDocument
                strikeListDocument.id = x.id;

                x.ref.collection(FirebaseConstraints.UserCollection).onSnapshot(
                    x => {
                        let strikeListDocumentUsers: StrikeListDocumentUser[] = []
                        x.forEach(y => {
                            let userDocument = y.data() as StrikeListDocumentUser;
                            strikeListDocumentUsers.push(userDocument)
                        })
                        const strikeList = this._strikeLists?.find(x => x.id == strikeListDocument.id)
                        if (strikeList)
                            strikeList.users = strikeListDocumentUsers
                    })
                this._strikeLists?.push(strikeListDocument)
            })
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onSnapshot()` returns `void`.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot

Could you try the following code?

```
// In the Same Class
const [strikes, setStrikes] = useState<StrikeListDocument[]>([]);

export const FirebaseGetStrikeLists2 = async (houseId: string) => {
  firestore()
    .collection(FirebaseConstraints.HouseCollection)
    .doc(houseId)
    .collection(FirebaseConstraints.StrikeSubCollection)
    .onSnapshot(async x => {
      let strikes: StrikeListDocument[] = [];

      x.forEach(async x => {
        const strikeListDocument = x.data() as StrikeListDocument;
        strikeListDocument.users = [];
        strikeListDocument.id = x.id;

        x.ref
          .collection(FirebaseConstraints.UserCollection)
          .onSnapshot(async x => {
            let strikeListUsers: StrikeListDocumentUser[] = [];
            x.forEach(async y => {
              let userDocument = y.data() as StrikeListDocumentUser;
              strikeListUsers.push(userDocument);
            });
            await Promise.all(strikeListUsers);
            console.log("users found: ", strikeListUsers.length);
            strikeListDocument.users = strikeListUsers;
          });
        console.log("users set in array: ", strikeListDocument.users.length);
        strikes.push(strikeListDocument);
      });

      // you should set state here. setStrikes() is useState returns.
      setStrikes(strikes);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Now the return type is a void. In a store class I set an observable property to the return value.

Comment: Thanks for your update, I had the same in my mind!!:)
I have edited my post. I think this is the best way to go, but it prefered a bit of code splitting. What do you think?:)

Comment: Sorry, I have not been used mobx. But LGTM.